# Google query - how to ignore formulas where filtering with WHERE

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to do something very simple:

```
=query(spreadsheet2!A2:X10, "Select * where B != '' ", -1)
```

Simply get all rows from the range where column B isn't empty. But this returns all rows, because the B column contains a formula. Comparing `B` with `is not null` yields the same result.

How can I ignore the formulas in query, so that it only returns rows where column B's *value* isn't empty?

Here's my attempt:

```
=query(popup1line!A2:X10, "Select * where B is not null", -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably caused by mixed type data in your table, and not by formulas. One way to deal with it is to force data into the same type. Try the following:

```
=query(arrayformula(spreadsheet2!A2:X10 & ""), "Select * where Col2 is not null", -1)
```

Comment: I want to ignore formulas though, will that do?

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. If I remove the formulas from the cells I'm testing (`B` or `Col2`), the query works as expected. But neither the code in the OP or your suggestion work effectively.

Comment: @pnuts - I can't share the sheet unfortunately. I've added my exact query to the OP. It works like a charm if said B column didn't contain the formula `=E14`. By now I've started resorting to Google Scripts though, which is a shame.